# Xively arduino get and put return take too long

Tags: arduino, xively

I wonder why it took so long to get the return from xively? I m using the arduino API from Xively. And Arduino mega adk + gsm shield

put : 17sec
get : 7 sec

as it will jam up the whole arduino code for too long, user input (buttons) will be ignored in this case.

anyone got the idea?

Answer (score 1):

It probably takes a long time since your GSM shield is likely using GPRS for data which is what you probably know as 2G cell network connection.

The speed of this GPRS connection is very slow, probably on the order of 50 or 60 kbps. GPRS and cell connections in general often also have quite high latency.

The only thing to try is to decrease your payload size, perhaps try CSV format if you are using JSON or XML.